# How to check Installation in Mac os

Tags: java, macos, command, javac

In my mac when I run `javac -version` command in terminal I get `No Java runtime present, requesting install.` but when I run `which javac` command I get `/usr/bin/javac`.

Do I need to install new jdk? And what should I do with the javac folder which is already present?

Answer (score 1):

Try `javac --version` in terminal